# Sql syntax error while creating `leave` table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem while creating table in my wamp server (version-2.2.22) and php (version 5.3.13).The error given below...

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'leave( lid INT AUTO_INCREMENT, empname VARCHAR(255), username
>   VARCHAR(255), ' at line 1

and here my code.pls help me..

```
create table leave(
lid INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
empname VARCHAR(255),
username VARCHAR(255),
nod INT,
sdate DATE,
edate DATE,
reason VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY(lid),
FOREIGN KEY(empID) REFERENCES users(empID)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LEAVE` is a reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html).  Surround it with backtics.

```
CREATE TABLE `leave` (
```